# Invalid column name Departments.DepartmentID

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the error below, and dont understand why, as the column DepartmentID does exist in the database, Here is my code

Basically I have two related tables (1) Departments with PK DepartmentID and (2) Departments_Category_Registration with FK DepartmentID

Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Categories)
    {

        ViewData["Dept"] = "No Records Found!";
        Categories = Categories.Replace("_", " ");


        //CHECK FOR INTEGER
        try
        { Int32.Parse(Categories); }
        catch //(Exception err)
        { }

        if (Categories != null)
        {




            if (Categories.Trim() != "")
            {
                Categories = Categories.ToLower().Trim();
                // DATABASE 2 - Main records
                var DataContext2 = _context.Departments_Category_Registration.Include(c => c.Departments)
                   .Where(r => r.Departments.Department_Name == Categories).Select(u => new Departments_Category_Registration
                   {
                       CategoryID = u.CategoryID,
                       Category_Name = u.Category_Name,
                       DepartmentID = u.DepartmentID,
                       Description = u.Description



                   });

                ViewData["Dept"] = Categories;
                return View(await DataContext2.ToListAsync());

            };
        };
        var DataContext = _context.Departments_Category_Registration.Include(c => c.Departments);
       return View(await DataContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

//ERROR MESSAGE

```
 return View(await DataContext2.ToListAsync());

SqlException: Invalid column name 'DepartmentsDepartmentID'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[ForeignKey]` annotation in `Departments_Category_Registration` class like below :

1.On the foreign key property in the dependent class, passing in the name of the navigation property:

```
  public class Departments_Category_Registration
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Departments ")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public Departments Departments { get; set; }   
}
```

2.On the navigation property in the dependent class, passing in the name of the foreign key property:

```
public class Departments_Category_Registration
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; } 

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID ")]
    public Departments Departments { get; set; }   
}
```

You could refer to  [this article about the ForeignKey Attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute) .